# When is it advantageous to constrain a join in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, query-optimization, constraints

For instance, say you have a query like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1 AND t1.year = t2.year
JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.field1 = t3.field1 AND t1.year = t3.year
JOIN table4 t4 ON t3.field2 = t4.field2 AND t3.year = t4.year
WHERE t1.year = '2010'
```

Is it faster to do this :

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1 AND t1.year = t2.year AND t2.year = '2010'
JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.field1 = t3.field1 AND t1.year = t3.year AND t3.year = '2010'
JOIN table4 t4 ON t3.field2 = t4.field2 AND t3.year = t4.year AND t4.year = '2010'
WHERE t1.year = '2010'
```

It is not always obvious which will be 'faster'.  Sometimes the execution plan in SQL Server 2005 says one is faster than the other, depending on the indexing.  Sometimes it does all hash matching, which appears to be CPU intensive versus a sort then a merge join which appears to be more IO intensive.  The real world results do not always mirror what one would expect given the results of the execution plan.

---

Can someone clarify for me some simple scenarios where one is better than the other?  Or at least verify if my understanding is correct?  It appears to me that if you are joining on columns that are indexed well, it is more efficient to not constrain the join with a year or some other piece of data, because it can use hash matching based on the index and has no need to sort and use a temp table.

However, if you are selecting and joining on non-indexed columns in both queries, adding the time constraint results in less rows to be processed and leads to a faster sort and merge join, even though it incurs some (more?) IO cost.

---

Also, it bothers me that the pre-join select from table2 does not take into account the limited subset of values that result from the where clause on table1, it appears to select all rows from table2 when not using a constraint on the join. Since the rows from table1 will be limited b WHERE t1.year = '2010' and the join is limited by t1.year = t2.year, shouldn't it follow that a join would only have to look at table2 where year = '2010'?

I wonder why it does not look at the where clause first, and select only matching rows before it even does the join, I'm sure there is some good reasoning behind this, but it escapes me, according to the execution plan, the number of rows looked at from table2 in that case does change depending on whether you have added t2.year = '2010' to the join or not.

Thank you in advance, and sorry for the long question. I'm trying to be as clear as possible. Please excuse my inexperience.

Comment: Since you asked "I wonder why it does not look at the where clause first", I thought I would give you the information that the logical query processing order goes like this: FROM (a subset of this step creates virtual tables based on joins and their ON filters, etc.), WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, SELECT (a subset of steps here processes the elements in the SELECT list), then ORDER BY is processed last. (There are a few more substeps that I did not include.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Is it faster?" No.

The query optimizer will decide which is the most restrictive resultset filter (and will usually do a good job provided your statistics are up to date).

Comment: +1 Although it depends on the exact query. It is possible to "trick" SQL Server (2008 R2, even) into choosing some bad plans, even in a simple case like that... but, mostly... yeah.

Comment: I have a query, similar to the above, that takes :50 without the time constraint and :20 with it, consistently.  The difference, per the exec plan, seems to be a series of RID Lookups.  Any insight on that situation?  (I know it's not great because I haven't given you an exact example, just curious about the possibilities.)

Comment: @John: I would post the executionplan

Comment: @Mitch I don't think I can make it anonymous enough. If I strip it down to just the main steps and times, will that be useful? (Also, would I just dump it in a comment?)  I can tell you the estimated subtree cost for the query is much less without the time constraint, but in practice it does not run as quickly Could this be an IO issue?

Comment: @Mitch ahh you nailed it and I didn't even realize it. :)  "update statistics" and now it makes sense, and the estimated costs are close to identical.  I think it was choosing a bad execution plan.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Having an extra filter adds no value: the optimiser work it out already. It makes the code harder to maintain though.

You can do it for OUTER JOINs because you can't filter in the WHERE on the outer table (changes to an INNER JOIN):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
table2 t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1 AND t1.year = t2.year and t2.x = 1
JOIN
table3 t3 on t1.field1 = t3.field1 AND t1.year = t3.year
...
WHERE
t1.year = '2010'
```

Comment: Thanks it makes sense on the outer joins.